# Find the closest point on a cylinder surface to a given line in c++

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection

I need a function that will find the closest point on a cylinder surface to a given line. Let's say the cylinder is centered along the z-axis({0, 0, 0}) and defined by its Radius R and half-length Z and the (infinite) line is defined by two 3D points A(x1,x2) and B(y1,y2). What is the best way to compute the point on the cylinder surface which is closest to this line?

Comment: If you don't know how to find the closest point, then SO isn't the place to ask that question. If you know how, and you're having problems with implementing, then show your attempt and what the issue is.

Comment: This is not C++; it is general geometry. Much more a math question than a C++ one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider skew lines in 3D - z-axis and your line.

Build the shortest line between them (it is perpensicular to both line).

Math of this calculation is described in "the shortest line" section [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/), example of implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234003/3d-line-intersection-code-not-working-properly/40236124#40236124).

If point S on z-axis (where the shortest line meets z-axis) is outside of cylinder, then the closest point lies on the circumference of cylinder top or bottom (use direction vector described below with zero z-component)

Otherwise calculate unit vector for the shortest line direction, multiply it by cylinder radius, add to point S

Also check case of distance < R - when line intersects cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

[explanation figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsaRz.png)

See the figure above. The idea is:

> 1- Because the cylinder is on the Z axis, we can project everything on
>   the (X,Y) plane, so we can work in 2D. So for example: A (-2,1,10)
>   becomes A(-2,1). Also the cylinder is treated as a circle.
>
> Let's call (D) the infinite line passing by A and B. And (C) the
>   circle (representing the cylinder in 2D)
>
> 2- We draw a triangle formed of 3 points: A, B, and the center of the
>   circle (C) (being the origin (0,0)),
>   like shown in the figure.
>
> 3- Let (L) be the line passing by the center of (C) and perpendicular
>   to (D) like shown in the figure.
>
> 4- The closest point will be the intersection of (C) and (L)

Now all the above can be done by simple mathematical equations.

First some definitions:

ax + by + c = 0 : is equation of a 2D line in the (X,Y) plane

Having 2 points A and B on a line (D) we can calculate the direction vector Vd of (D)

> Vd ( B.x-A.x, B.y-A.y)

With that direction vector we can calculate the equation (ax+by+c) of (D).

> a = Vd.y
>   b = -Vd.x
>   c = Vd.x*A.y - A.x*Vd.y

With that equation we can calculate the normal vector Vn of (D)

> Vn (a, b)

Applying these formulas on your question:

1- We calculate the direction vector Vd of the infinite line (D) passing by A and B.
2- From Vd we get the equation of (D)
3- From the equation we get Vn
4- Because Vn is "pointing" from (D) to the (C), we must flip It by multiplying each coordinate with (-1). So we create a new direction Vector: Vd2 ( -Vn.x, -Vn.y)
5- Now Vd2 is the direction vector of (L) which isthe red line in the figure.
6- Now we just have to get the point on the circle (C) (cylinder) following Vd2 which will be the closest point on the circle surface which is closest to the line (D).
To do that we normalize Vd2 and we multiply It by the circle (C) radius. We will get the closest point's X and Y coordinates: X = Vd.normalized * (C).radius and Y = Vd.normalized * (C).radius.

7- Now you got the closest point put only in 2d, let's call It point J. So you have J's x and y coordinates.
To get the z coordinate you replace x and y in the line 3D equation with J's x and y, you solve it and get the z coordinate of J.

The code below is written in C# and tested visually in Unity 3D. It should be simple to write in C++ after understanding what is written above.

Note: here Vector2 is also used to hold the coordinates of 2d points not only 2d vectors. It is just a class that has 2 properties: int x, and int y. And droite means line but in french

```
    public Transform A, B ;
    public Transform cylinder ;
    public Transform closest ;

    Vector3 pointA ;
    Vector3 pointB ;

    Vector2 a, b ;
    Vector2 vd, vn ;

    Droite d ;
    Cylinder c ;

    Vector2 inter;

    public void Start () {
        c = new Cylinder (0.5f, 10);
    }

    public void Update () {
        pointA = A.transform.localPosition;
        pointB = B.transform.localPosition;

        a = (Vector2) pointA;
        b = (Vector2) pointB;
        vd = b-a;

        d = new Droite (pointA, vd);
        d.cal_euqation ();

        Vector3 result = closest_point_on_cylinder (d,c);

        closest.transform.localPosition = result;

    }

    public Vector2 closest_point_on_cylinder (Droite d, Cylinder c){
        Droite d2= new Droite (Vector2.zero, d.vn);
        return Vector2.one * (-d2.vd.normalized) * c.r;
    }


}

public class Droite {

    public float a,b,c;
    public Vector2 pointA, vd, vn;

    public Droite (Vector2 _pointA, Vector2 _vd){
        pointA = _pointA;
        vd = _vd ;
    }

    public void cal_euqation () {
        a = vd.y;
        b = -vd.x;
        c = (vd.x*pointA.y - pointA.x*vd.y);

        vn = new Vector2 (a,b);
    }

    public float getX (float y){
        return -(b*y + c) / a ;
    }

}

public class Cylinder {

    public float x,y,h,r; // s  y  height  radius

    public Cylinder (float _r, float _h){
        r = _r ;
        h = _h;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @ELA, thanks for your answer, could you elaborate a bit on how to get the z component? Thanks1