Finding the intersection of two lines a given perpendicular distance from the line of intersection
I'm looking for help to solve the following situation. I have a line segment defined by two points P1 and P2. And I have a ray that starts at P3 and intersects segment P1P2 at P4. I want to calculate P5 so that it is always a given length l perpendicular distance from P1P2.

This is my current approach: When ray P3 intersects P1P2 (as a conditional, so P4 isn't even used), I then calculate P1'P2' where P1' and P2' are translated by the perpendicular vector towards P3 (shown below) and I find ray P3 intersection with P1'P2'.

This seems a wonky way to do it to me, though. First I have to find the orientation of P1, P2, and P3 and use that to get the right perpendicular vector and then I have to do my line intersection all over again with P1'P2' to find P5. All this just so that P5 is always a specific distance l away from the segment P1P2.
It seems like there should be a more straightforward way to solve this with less math for the computer to perform, but I don't have a strong enough math background to figure it out. And since I'm using vectors, that makes it more difficult to think about outside the tools I already have (line intersection was also high school math).
The use case is for collision detection. I've drawn P1P2 with a horizontal slope, but it isn't necessarily the case that it always will be. I will be very surprised if anyone tells me my current solution is the right one and I'm hoping someone can point me toward a better way.
PS, my knowledge of math notation is also not strong. If there's a request to see my work, I'll have to show you using C#.

You can solve this with trig, but you actually don't need that, if I understand your question correctly. You're dealing with points so let's say P3 is x3, y3 and P4 is x4, y4 and so on. You are trying to solve for x5 and y5. Correct?
y5 is easy because it's just y4 minus some distance L (going upper case because lower case l is ambiguous).
y5 = y4 - L
Now for x5 you need to move back from x4 some distance D, just as you moved back distance L from y4. This distance D will be a proportionate distance along the x axis to what L was along the y axis. Moving back proportionately will keep you on that line from P3 to P4.
x5 = x4 - D
D = (ratio of L to total movement on y axis) * (total movement on x axis)

To get D we need the ratio of L to the total movement along the y axis:
R = L/(y4 - y3)
Now that we have the ratio, we multiply it by the total movement on the x axis:
D = L/(y4 - y3) * (x4 - x3)
Substituting D back in to the equation above for x5 and doing a bit of rearranging:
x5 = x4 - L(x4 - x3)/(y4 - y3)
So there you have both coordinates for your new point P5 in terms of known numbers:
x5 = x4 - L(x4 - x3)/(y4 - y3)
y5 = y4 - L


Thank you for finding a non-trig solution. What you described makes so much sense also. I'll implement this when I get home and update if I run into another problem. The only part that looks tricky is when P1 and P2 are not perfectly horizontal.

Yeah so upon reflection, the above still won't quite work without trigonometry because the line won't always be horizontal. I have to first rotate all points until P1 and P2 form a horizontal line. I don't know if there is a smarter way to do this, but I have to find what to multiply all x and y values by in order to get P1.y == P2.y.

So... to rotate all my points for the above math, take the Arctan of P2 - P1 = theta... then solve x and y for all my points using x' = x cos(theta) - y sin(theta), y' =  x sin(theta) + y cos(theta)... that's a lot of trig. And once I find my P5, reverse-rotate it back by theta into the original coord space. Stop me if I'm wrong and there's a simpler way.

Ok, I've had a chance to work on this some more, and I've found a solution that doesn't use trigonometry, but it does involve several square roots due to vector normalization and vector length calculations. I'm going to try to post an answer. Your answer above helped a lot though in making me realize the easy way was to use the ratio of the closest distance of the ray start point with the minimum distance to stop away from the boundary.

With the help of YoungZaphod's answer, I've found one way to solve this problem. Here is a visual explanation of what I'm doing:

I know it's ugly, but this is the result of implementing this in Unity. I'll post the code here for anyone who might want to use it in the future. The code is not pretty and I've sourced the other answers on Stack Overflow and YouTube where I took code for 1) Line Intersection with Vectors 2) Closest distance calculation with Vector and Point. I'm still open to refinements or better ways to do this. And if anyone finds a bug testing this themselves, let me know.
Finally, I'm aware of an edge case where if the buffer is large enough and the intersection is close enough to the start/end of the "wall" the Green P7 will appear to lie outside the wall segment P1P2. This would be notable if the length L is used to represent the radius of circles colliding with the walls. This edge-case is outside my concern at the moment and I'm not going to try to solve it here.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DotProductSceneLogic : MonoBehaviour {

  //Set these values in the Unity Inspector
  public Vector2 wallTail;
  public Vector2 wallHead;

  public Vector2 pathTail;
  public Vector2 pathHead;

  private void OnDrawGizmos() {
    int n = 10;
    Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
    for (int i = -n; i < n; i++) {
      Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(i, n), new Vector2(i, -n));
      Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(n, i), new Vector2(-n, i));
    }

    Gizmos.color = Color.black;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(wallTail, wallHead);

    Gizmos.color = Color.white;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(pathTail, pathHead);
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(pathHead, 0.15f);
    Vector2 intersect;
    bool collision = getLineIntersection(pathTail, pathHead, wallTail, wallHead, out intersect);

    if (!collision) {
      return;
    }

    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(intersect, .2f);

    //This is negative or posititive depending on orientation.
    float shortestDistToWall = distanceFromLine(wallTail, wallHead, pathHead);

    const float buffer = 1f;
    float ratio = buffer / Mathf.Abs(shortestDistToWall);

    float d = Vector2.Distance(pathHead, intersect);
    float newDistance = d - d * ratio;

    Vector2 newPos = pathHead + (pathTail - pathHead).normalized * newDistance;
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(newPos, .2f);

    //The following is not necessary to calculate, just for debug:
    Vector2 perpendicular = (wallTail - wallHead).normalized;
    perpendicular = new Vector2(-perpendicular.y, perpendicular.x);

    Vector2 p3 = pathHead + perpendicular * shortestDistToWall;
    Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(p3, .12f);
  }

  //Version from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvlIYX9cgls
  private bool getLineIntersection(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3, Vector2 p4, out Vector2 result) {
    //Notes:
    //Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079842/602680
    //Use the vector representation of a line as shown. B = the base point, ie tail.
    //[x, y] = [m_x, m_y] * t + [b_x, b_y]

    //Vector2 pathMagnitude = pathTail - pathHead;
    //Vector2 wallMagnitude = wallTail - wallHead;

    //Now we are going to have two equations, one for each line.
    //(1)[x, y] = [m_x_1, m_y_1] * t + [b_x_1, b_y_1]
    //(2)[x, y] = [m_x_2, m_y_2] * s + [b_x_2, b_y_2]

    float x1 = p1.x;
    float y1 = p1.y;
    float x2 = p2.x;
    float y2 = p2.y;
    float x3 = p3.x;
    float y3 = p3.y;
    float x4 = p4.x;
    float y4 = p4.y;

    /*
    float a = (x4 - x3) * (y3 - y1) - (y4 - y3) * (x3 - x1);
    float b = (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1) - (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1);
    float c = (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1);
    */
    //get magnitude values for P1P2
    float x21 = x2 - x1;
    float y21 = y2 - y1;

    //?
    float x31 = x3 - x1;
    float x43 = x4 - x3;

    //?
    float y31 = y3 - y1;
    float y43 = y4 - y3;

    float a = x43 * y31 - y43 * x31;
    float b = x43 * y21 - y43 * x21;
    float c = x21 * y31 - y21 * x31;

    if (b == 0) {
      //Lines are parallel and do not intersect
      if (a == 0) {
        //The lines are collinear
      }
      result = Vector2.zero;
      return false;
    }

    //The scalar that tells us how much to multiply the magnitude of the vector by to get our result.
    float alpha = a / b;

    //float x0 = x1 + alpha * (x2 - x1);
    //float y0 = y1 + alpha * (y2 - y1);

    //result = new Vector2(x0, y0);
    result = p1 + alpha * (p2 - p1);

    if (alpha > 0 && alpha <= 1) {
      float beta = c / b;
      if (beta > 0 && beta <= 1) {
        //If both scalars of the magnitude are between 0 and 1 they are between the two points
        //used to define both line segments
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  //From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77928107/602680
  private float distanceFromLine(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3) {
    //For line p1p2, get the shortest distance to p3.
    float p1_0 = p1.x;
    float p2_0 = p2.x;
    float p3_0 = p3.x;
    float p1_1 = p1.y;
    float p2_1 = p2.y;
    float p3_1 = p3.y;
    float p2_0_minus_p1_0 = p2_0 - p1_0;
    float p2_1_minus_p1_1 = p2_1 - p1_1;
    float p3_0_minus_p1_0 = p3_0 - p1_0;
    float p3_1_minus_p1_1 = p3_1 - p1_1;
    float closest_distance = (p2_0_minus_p1_0 * p3_1_minus_p1_1 - p3_0_minus_p1_0 * p2_1_minus_p1_1) / Mathf.Sqrt(p2_0_minus_p1_0 * p2_0_minus_p1_0 + p2_1_minus_p1_1 * p2_1_minus_p1_1);
    return closest_distance;
  }
}

